Mocking internal change handler in MUI component
I am trying to write a test for the following code.  It uses MUI components to render a checkbox with label.
import React from 'react';
import { FormControlLabel, Checkbox } from '@mui/material';

function FilterCheckbox(props) {
    return(
        <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox/>}
        label={props.text}
        sx={{ width: 1 }}
          // handleChange is defined above this function
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(props, event)}/>
    );
};

The problem is, when I am writing my test, I can render the component, but it does not take onChange as a prop, and does not have a way to mock the handleChange function:
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import FilterCheckbox from './FilterCheckbox';

describe('FilterCheckbox', () => {
    test('toggles checked and unchecked', () => {
        const tagName='Test label'
        const tagId='1'
        render(<FilterCheckbox text={tagName} key={tagId} tagId={tagId}/>);

        const checkbox = screen.getByRole('checkbox');

        expect(checkbox.checked).toBeFalsy()
        
        fireEvent(
            checkbox,
            new MouseEvent('click', {
              bubbles: true,
              cancelable: true,
            }),
          )

        // Test fails here, because "handleChange" has not completed its message to the server
        expect(checkbox.checked).toBeTruthy()
    })
})

My test is failing because of some internal logic in the handleChange function that calls to the server cannot complete, because there is no server for it to reach during the test.  I'd like to mock out this logic, but I'm not sure how to do that, given that it's encapsulated in this component and isn't exposed as a prop.  Is there a way with Jest to mock out this internal function?  Or to provide a response to it from a mocked "server" so that it finishes running and this test can pass?
In case you'd like to suggest ideas on a mocked "server," here is the handleChange function:
import filterSocket from '../SupportingModules/FilterSocket';

const handleChange = (props, event) => {
    const checkboxLabel = props.text;
    const socket = filterSocket;  // Websocket connection
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        'type':'filterChange',
        'filterName': checkboxLabel,
        'filterId': props.tagId,
        'filterState': (event.target.checked ? "on" : "off")
    }));
};

The error I am getting when trying to run my test is:
InvalidStateError: Still in CONNECTING state.
Full FilterCheckbox.js file:

import React from 'react';
import { FormControlLabel, Checkbox } from '@mui/material';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';

import filterSocket from '../SupportingModules/FilterSocket';


/**
 * Detects when a FilterCheckbox is clicked, and sends a message to backend with updated state of filter.
 * 
 * @param {object} props Contains props passed to the component.
 * @param {string} props.text String label of the checkbox; matches name of tag to filter.
 * @param {number} props.tagId The numerical tag ID to filter for when this box is checked.
 * @param {event} event Detects when box has been clicked (checked or unchecked).
 */
const handleChange = (props, event) => {
    const checkboxLabel = props.text;
    const socket = filterSocket;
    const selectionMessage = "FilterCheckbox: " + (event.target.checked ? "" : "un") + "checked " + props.tagId;
    console.log(selectionMessage);
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        'type':'filterChange',
        'filterName': checkboxLabel,
        'filterId': props.tagId,
        'filterState': (event.target.checked ? "on" : "off")
    }));
};

/**
 * Renders a checkbox that allows (de)selection of a tag for image filtering.
 * 
 * @param {object} props Contains props passed to the component.
 * @param {string} props.text String label of the checkbox; matches name of tag to filter.
 * @param {number} props.tagId The numerical tag ID to filter for when this box is checked.
 * @returns The FilterCheckbox component to be rendered in the app.
 */
function FilterCheckbox(props) {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const largeScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md'));
    const largeScreenStyle = {transform: "scale(1.15)", margin: "0 0 0 3%"};
    const smallScreenStyle = {transform: "scale(1.75)", margin: "0 1% 0 2.5%"};

    return(
        <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox style={ largeScreen ? largeScreenStyle : smallScreenStyle }/>}
        label={props.text}
        componentsProps={{ typography: {fontSize: {'xs': 40, 'md': 25}}}}
        sx = {{ width: 0.98 }} // ensures that one item takes up one row
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(props, event)}/>
    );
};

export default FilterCheckbox;



And FilterSocket.js:
const filterSocket = new WebSocket(
    'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/filter-socket/'
);

filterSocket.onopen = () => {
    console.log('FilterSocket connected!');
    filterSocket.send(JSON.stringify({'type': 'message', 'message': 'FilterSocket Connected!'}));
};

filterSocket.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log('Filter socket has closed unexpectedly')
};

export default filterSocket;


Is there any other relevant code missing? As far as I can see you are not preventing the default behaviour of the click event in your component code, so the fact that your socket operation has not finished would not prevent your checkbox to change its state.

@mgarcia I believe the checkbox state is indeed changing, but as soon as it does the handleChange function fires, but because it can't create the websocket connection, it creates an error.  This error is causing my test to fail, which is why I'm curious if there is a way to mock it out, since it's not what I'm trying to test in this instance.

As you stated in the comments, the problem is not really with your expectation but with your code generating an error due to the call to socket.send.
You can avoid that by mocking your socket module so that the real call is not performed in your test. In order to accomplish that it is enough to add the line jest.mock('../SupportingModules/FilterSocket') after the imports on your test.
Calling jest.mock only with the first argument automocks all the module exported methods for the current test file.
This way you could also check that when a checkbox is checked the information is sent through the socket:
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import filterSocket from '../SupportingModules/FilterSocket';
import FilterCheckbox from './FilterCheckbox';

jest.mock('../SupportingModules/FilterSocket', () => ({
    onopen: jest.fn(),
    onclose: jest.fn(),
    send: jest.fn(),
    close: jest.fn()
}));

describe('FilterCheckbox', () => {
    test('toggles checked and unchecked', () => {
        const tagName='Test label'
        const tagId='1'
        render(<FilterCheckbox text={tagName} key={tagId} tagId={tagId}/>);

        const checkbox = screen.getByRole('checkbox');

        expect(checkbox.checked).toBeFalsy()
        
        fireEvent(
            checkbox,
            new MouseEvent('click', {
              bubbles: true,
              cancelable: true,
            }),
          )

        expect(checkbox.checked).toBeTruthy();
        expect(filterSocket.send).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})


Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')]
This is with your code copy-pasted into FilterSocket.test.js without any edits, for good measure.  Is there anything else I need to do to mock the filterSocket module in my FilterSocket component?

That may be due to the way you export your methods inside FilterSocket, or maybe the place where the filterSocket. You said the handleChange method was placed in the same FilterCheckbox but you posted them in different sections of your question. Maybe they are not placed in the same file?

I have updated with the full, unbroken FilterCheckbox.js file, maybe that will help illustrate my setup.  The test was already the full code in that file

I'm thinking it's maybe a better idea, instead of calling socket.send inside the FilterCheckbox module, to create a send method as part of the filterSocket, and that might make it easier to mock out.  Does that sound reasonable or am I way off the mark?

Although it wouldn't be a bad idea to abstract a little bit the methods that FilterSocket exposes, I'm afraid the problem will not be solved by that change. The problem we are seeing now is caused because FilterSocket exports an instance of WebSocket and the automock is probably only mocking the onopen and onclose methods defined in the module but not the methods provided by WebSocket instance.
We can avoid that by explicitly defining an implementation in the call to jest.mock. I will update the code in my answer. The changes are in the call to jest.mock.

That looks promising, and makes more clear to me how I can extend this pattern if other problems crop up.  Will try again soon and get back to you

I did pull out the socket.send logic into a method of filterSocket, but I think the real trick here was what you showed me with mocking methods using jest.mock and jest.fn().  Seeing it in practice with my own code helped me wrap my head around it a lot better, I'm going to go back and re-read the docs on this with this new understanding in mind.  Thank you @mgarcia!
